# Dividing equally a vector matlab

Tags: matlab

in MFCCs i have specified `f_low` and `f_high` which are my frequency min and max bands, and i am about to compute N equally distanced mel values between these two frequency values. So i wrote

```
f_low=1000;  
f_high=fs/2;
filt_num=26;  % number of filters
stp=round(f_high/filt_num); % step 
f=f_low:stp:f_high; % my frequency vector
```

but i can't divide equally my `f` vector, maybe there is a function in matlab that does it , or am i missing something? Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by divide equally? Do you want the first half of the entries in one subvector and the second half in another? or do they need to be ordered?

Comment: Or for ex fs=20,000 then f_high=10,000 therefore stp = 10k/26=385, f gives you values like 1000        1385        1770        2155        2540        2925        3310 and so on until 9855? what do you expect?

Comment: i need to create a new vector that will have 26 elements and they will have equal distances between them , starting from f_low and ending to f_high

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of digging around leads me to believe you want a linearly spaced vector with `filt_num` entries, starting at `f_low` and ending at `f_high`. You should use `linspace` for that as follows:

```
f = linspace(f_low,f_high,filt_num);
```

This is essentially the same as your last two lines of code. Keep in mind your code only works when `f_high` is larger than `f_low`. `linspace` does not have this issue, as it also supports descending vectors.